# SQL in MS Access: retrieve field name from another field

Tags: sql, ms-access

There are two tables like following:

Table 1

```
code integer,
d1 single,
d2 single,
...
d6 single.
```

Table 2

```
code integer,
d string
```

Field `d` in Table 2 is supposed to contain "d1", "d2",...,"d5" or "d6".
Now I try to compose a query with fields like `code (integer)` and `d_value (single)`, where `d_value` retrieve value `d1`, `d2`,... or `d6` (from Table 1) depending of field `d` value in table 1. Now the `switch` function is used, and it works:

```
SELECT Table1.code, Table2.d,
Switch(Trim([d])="d1",[d1],
Trim([d])="d2",[d2],
Trim([d])="d3",[d3],
Trim([d])="d4",[d4],
Trim([d])="d5",[d5],
Trim([d])="d6",[d6])
AS [d_value] FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.[code] = Table2.[code];
```

However, I feel (and believe) that there is more natural way rather than writing down six cases `d1`, ... ,`d6` in the `switch` function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Andre, thanks for make formatting better.

Comment: you can use vba in ms access to create dynamic queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Table1 of the form

```
code  d1   d2   d3   d4   d5   d6
----  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---
   1  1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6
   2  2.1  2.2  2.3  2.4  2.5  2.6
```

the `Switch` approach is the practical way to do it using static SQL. However, if

- you find that you are using the `Switch` approach in a lot of queries,
- there are actually more than 6 categories, or
- the number of categories may change

then you should probably reorganize Table1 to be

```
code  category  d_value
----  --------  -------
   1  d1            1.1
   1  d2            1.2
   1  d3            1.3
   1  d4            1.4
   1  d5            1.5
   1  d6            1.6
   2  d1            2.1
   2  d2            2.2
   2  d3            2.3
   2  d4            2.4
   2  d5            2.5
   2  d6            2.6
```

so you can simply do

```sql
SELECT Table1.code, Table2.d, Table1.d_value
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 
    ON Table1.code = Table2.code AND Table1.category = Table2.d
```

To recreate the original "wide" form of Table1 you can always use

```sql
TRANSFORM Min([d_value]) AS MinOfd_value
SELECT [code]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY [code]
PIVOT [category]
```

Comment: Gord Thompson, thanks for useful answer. However, the problem is to obtain the 'narrow' form of Table1 from the the 'wide' form (in the question the 'narrow' form is Table2. Reverse transformation, as you are mentioning, can be done by `transform ... pivot`.

Comment: In fact, the problem could be solved creating auxiliary query like `select code, 'd1' as d from Table1 union ... select code, 'd6' as d from Table1`. It looks slightly better than `switch` function, but also requires writing down six cases of `d`, and may work slowly because of additional `join`.

Comment: @Spectorsky - Yes, something like that would be a typical "unpivot" query in Access. And yes, it would likely be slower than maintaining the table "unpivoted" in its natural state, mainly because you would not be able to use indexes on the derived columns that you've UNIONed together.